# Adobe Acrobat Reader DC: strange search results

Tags: adobe, acrobat, adobe-reader

Acrobat Reader DC has produced strange search results:

[image]

Is it a bug?

Host OS: Windows 10.

Software version: 2020.009.20067.

Comment: Your question is not appropriate for this community: "About general computing hardware and software. This question is more likely to get an answer on Super User."

Comment: Thanks, David. Will ask on Super User then.